# Shouldn't this code compile according to 12.8p2 in the Standard?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

This code doesn't compile in VS2010. It emits error C2440: 'argument' : cannot convert from 'A' to 'A &', but according to 12.8p2 in the Standard, `A::A(A&)` is a valid copy constructor and `a` is an lvalue in the expression `A b = foo(a);` in `main()`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:

    int x;
    A(int a) { x = a; std::cout << "Constructor\n"; }
    A(A& other) { x = other.x; std::cout << "Copy ctor\n"; }
    A(A&& other) { x = other.x; other.x = 0; std::cout << "Move ctor\n"; }
};

A foo(A a) 
{
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    A a(5);
    A b = foo(a);
}
```

Comment: Compiles and runs fine in GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: Does it call the move ctor, to copy the return value from foo() to b?

Comment: Yes, see here: http://ideone.com/Ykwm2Z

Comment: Do you know why NRVO was not implemented?

Comment: [This site](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/SUn) compiles the code fine on VS 2012 CTP, so this is probably a VS2010 bug.

Comment: I've just realized NRVO cannot be used as foo() returns its own argument.

Comment: Compiles fine on my copy of VC2010 Ultimate Version 10.0.40219 SP1Rel with VC++ Version 16.00.40219.01

Comment: `cl.exe` version 16.00.40219.01 also compiles this just fine for me. So is this something that got fixed in VC++ 2010 SP1?  Can the OP post the version of `cl.exe` that fails to compile the example?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't know how to get this info using the IDE. But there's something I forgot to tell. I used the compiler switch "Disable Language Extensions" set to Yes. The default is No.

Comment: In the IDE set the "C/C++ | General | Suppress Startup Banner" project property to "No".  The pre-SP1 compiler is version 16.00.30319.01. Also, it might be significant if you're building for x86 or x64 (but I doubt it).

Comment: @MichaelBurr You're right. Mine is a pre-SP1 compiler. Thanks.

Comment: @interjay It seems like this a bug in the compiler. I will be glad to accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends on what standard you are talking about. Assuming C++11 then my take is that it should be OK and should produce the following result:

```
Constructor  <- Construction of 'a' in main
Copy ctor    <- Construction of 'a' in foo
Move ctor    <- Move from foo's return value into b
```

As you point out the a that gets passed into foo is an lvalue. However, the return value from foo is an rvalue and should therefore invoke either the const A& copy constructor (non-existent) in the pre C++11 case, or the move constructor in the C++11 case.